# Function which takes function/lambda/class with overloaded() as argument

Tags: c++, function, comparator, functor

I need write a function which can take another function/lambda/class with () operator overloaded as a parametr and correctly work with them (like 3th arg of std::sort.
What it looks like in terms of C++ syntax?

Comment: Okay... Did you look at how `std::sort` is defined and copy that?

Comment: It usually works as either `std::function`, if your function can't be made a template, or a template of functor type.

Comment: Yes I looked but it's too hard to understand that coding style -_-

Comment: @RayZieger Just take the callable as a templated parameter.

Comment: What don't you understand about `template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );`?

Comment: "function/lambda/class with () operator overloaded" is commonly given the term **callable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a function template (like `std::sort`) with a template parameter that you assume is callable:

```
template<typename Func>
void myFunction(Func f)
{
    f();
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
void normalFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Normal function.\n";
}

struct Functor {
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Functor object.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Functor functor;

    myFunction(normalFunction);
    myFunction(functor);
    myFunction([]{ std::cout << "Lambda.\n"; });
}
```

This will print:

```
Normal function.
Functor object.
Lambda.
```

Answer (score -1):

For functions parameters, as @NathanOliver mentioned, it is better to use template param as a function:

```
template<typename CompFunc>
int myfunction(CompFunc func, int a, int b) {
    return func(a, b) + 20;
}

float comp(double a, double b) {
    return (float)(b - a);
}

int main() {
    cout << myfunction(comp, 1, 2); // Prints: 21
    return 0;
}
```

However, there are some cases that you can't use template (for example- function parameter inside the main function).
For those cases, function variable looks like that in C:

```
ret_val (*function_parameter_name) (func_param_type1, func_param_type2, ..);
```

And in C++ it looks like that:

```
std::function<ret_val(func_param_type1, func_param_type2, ..)> function_parameter_name;
```

**function_parameter_name** - you will use it like: `function_parameter_name(p1, p2); // Call the function`

**func_param_typeX** - can be int/double...

**ret_val** - the function's return value type

---

**Example**:

```
float comp(double a, double b) {
    return (float)(b - a);
}

int main() {
    std::function<float(double, double)> my_comp;
    std::cout << my_comp(5.2, 3.9) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` in the interface is normally overkill.  A template allows you to take callables without having to use the expensive type erasure `std::function` uses.

Comment: @NathanOliver you right, fixed, thx.

Comment: calling `std::function` the "general" representation of functions in c++ is rather misleading